# Asterisk - How can i bookmark audio file

Tags: java, streaming, asterisk

I need bookmark audio file streaming.

How can i stream file but not start at 0? like start at 1 minute or something like this.
Anyone please give me a tip.
Edit: How can i get byte of what part played? Because Offset: offset byte to start playing so i need get byte for bookmark.

Comment: Did you try the framePos method within the AudioInputStream class?

Answer (score 0):

You have application ControlPlayback which allow playback with offset.

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application ControlPlayback 

  -= Info about application 'ControlPlayback' =- 

[Synopsis]
Play a file with fast forward and rewind. 

[Description]
This application will play back the given <filename>.
It sets the following channel variables upon completion:
${CPLAYBACKSTATUS}: Contains the status of the attempt as a text string
    SUCCESS
    USERSTOPPED
    ERROR
${CPLAYBACKOFFSET}: Contains the offset in ms into the file where playback
was at when it stopped. '-1' is end of file.
${CPLAYBACKSTOPKEY}: If the playback is stopped by the user this variable
contains the key that was pressed.

[Syntax]
ControlPlayback(filename[,skipms[,ff[,rew[,stop[,pause[,restart[,options]]]]]]])

[Arguments]
skipms
    This is number of milliseconds to skip when rewinding or fast-fo
    rwarding.
ff
    Fast-forward when this DTMF digit is received. (defaults to '#')
rew
    Rewind when this DTMF digit is received. (defaults to '*')
stop
    Stop playback when this DTMF digit is received.
pause
    Pause playback when this DTMF digit is received.
restart
    Restart playback when this DTMF digit is received.
options
    o(time): 
        time - Start at <time> ms from the beginning of the file.



[See Also]
Not available
```